# Jplayer playlist is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hello and thank you for any help provided. I am brand new to web development. I realizes this looks absolutely terrible, however I am trying to get functionality before I style it. PHP has been one nightmare after another.

I am pulling a list of songs form a mysql database that are supposed to be put into a jplayer playlist. I for the life of me cannot see why I keep getting this error: jplayer.php: Uncaught ReferenceError: jPlayerPlaylist is not defined. I need help debugging this, and please remember I am brand new... I know I'm an awful programmer.

```
    <?
   $localhost='127.0.0.1';
   $username='root';
   $password='';
   $database='radio';
   $link = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password, $database);
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Radio Station </title>
  <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">      </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>

  <link type="text/css" href="skin/pink.flag/css/jplayer.pink.flag.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#.php">Noonish Nineties</a></li>
     <li><a href="#.php">Late Afternoon Indie</a></li>
     <li><a href="#.php">Late With Nocturnal</a></li>
     </ul>
     </header>

     <section id="container">
      <style>

      #container 
          {
          position: relative;
          width: 95%;
          padding-top: 150px;
          padding-left: 100px;
          padding-right: 10px;
          margin: 15 auto;
          font-family: Sans-Serif;
          font-size: 120%;
          border: 5px solid gray;
          background-color: white;                    

          }
      </style>

      <?php
      $localhost='127.0.0.1';
      $username='root';
      $password='';
      $database='radio';
      $link = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password, $database);
      $baseurl = "music/";
      $sql2 = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(url) as path FROM track WHERE trackid IN
        (SELECT pt.trackid from playlisttrack pt, track t, playlist p WHERE           t.trackid = pt.trackid 
        AND pt.playlistid = p.playlistid AND p.playlistid = 60002)";
      if($s2_query = mysqli_query($link,$sql2))
      {

      while ($row = $s2_query->fetch_assoc()) 
          {
              $playlist = "[" . "'" . $row['path'] . "'" . "]";
          }

      }
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var playlist = <?php echo $playlist;?>;
      var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_N",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
      }, playlist, {
        playlistOptions: {
          enableRemoveControls: true
        },
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        audioFullScreen: false // Allows the audio poster to go full screen           via keyboard
      });
      //var cssSelector = { jPlayer: "#playlist_1", cssSelectorAncestor:           "#playlist_container" };

      //var options = { swfPath: "/js", supplied: "mp3", smoothPlayBar:           true, autoPlay: true, keyEnabled: true, shuffleOnLoop: true, wmode: "window" };
      //var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist,           options);
      });
      </script>
      <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
      <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio" role="application" aria-          label="media player">
        <div class="jp-type-single">
          <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
            <div class="jp-volume-controls">
              <button class="jp-mute" role="button"           tabindex="0">mute</button>
              <button class="jp-volume-max" role="button" tabindex="0">max           volume</button>
              <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-controls-holder">
              <div class="jp-controls">
                <button class="jp-play" role="button"           tabindex="0">play</button>
                <button class="jp-stop" role="button"           tabindex="0">stop</button>
              </div>
              <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                  <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="jp-current-time" role="timer" aria-          label="time">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="jp-duration" role="timer" aria-          label="duration">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="jp-toggles">
                <button class="jp-repeat" role="button"           tabindex="0">repeat</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-details">
            <div class="jp-title" aria-label="title">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to           a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/"           target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      </section>
      <?php
      mysqli_close($link);
      ?>
      </body>
```

thank you.

Comment: Try keeping only one copy of library (so throw `/js/jquery.min.js` and `/js/jquery.jplayer.js` away). Sometimes it gets buggy when two library of same kind is presented.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried removing the reference to both libraries and that did not work. I also tried removing the reference to every combination of libraries and the error persists.

Comment: Press `ctrl + U` and go to `jplayer.js` link, check if URL is fine

Comment: yes the URL works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jPlayerPlaylist is an add-on for jplayer, it's not included by default, so u have to include it first, u can find it in dist/add-on folder